# The linked server has been created but failed a connection test

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

This is the first time I add Linked Server in SQL Server 2008. The remote server is SQL Server 2005.

Now I specified the following,

[image]

[image]

But I'm receiving the below error

```
SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)
```

Comment: I've never seen the IP\instance used that way in linked server... not saying it's wrong, but have you just tried the server name for the linked server field? Since, it is on your network

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give this a try. This is how I create all my linked servers:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still I cannot. But I have some confusion regarding the names of the above fields. Is the 'DATABASE_NAME' the name of the server shown in SQL Server Management Studio ?

Comment: DATABASE_NAME is the name of the instance of SQL Server on that machine.

Comment: I had some network issues that I fixed and could connect to db. But cannot query the db, I get 'Login failed for user' error.

Comment: Make sure the user info is correct and has all the required permissions on the database.I would test everything with the 'sa' account and then change that when it goes to production.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to follow your instructions to successfully create the linked server. Quick question - is there any way to name the linked server anything other than "MSSQLSERVER" using this configuration?

Comment: Type whatever name you want in that box.

Comment: I think, this is the least secure option to configure linked server!

Comment: @ShekarKola  - why?

Comment: @briskovich, Because any logins from Local SQL Server (as your post BRIANBPC) can execute the queries on linked server (192.168.20.24) even though there are no permissions assigned. Unfortunately, you cannot DENY access to linked servers for certain logins.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link I found useful to create linked servers: [SQL Server and Postgresql linked servers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/)